# C, rounding problems. UWORD, ints, and doubles

Tags: c, arithmetic-expressions

I have a few questions as to what the results of these operations are.

Firstly, if I have two integers and divide them and save the result in a double. Will there be any rounding issues such that 1/2 will equal .5 and not 1.

```
double ratio = int1/int2;
```

Second, if I now have this ratio and multiply it by a UWORD will there be any problems?

```
UWORD word1 = 4098;
UWORD word2 = ratio * word1;
```

By the way, I do get compiler warning when I do do these

```
 narrowing or signed-to-unsigned type conversion found: double to unsigned short
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast `int1` to a `double` so the compiler know to use floating point calculations (instead of integer ones):

```
double ratio = ((double) int1) / int2;
```

To store the floating point calcualtion of `ration * word1` in the `UWORD` you need to cast it again (to prevent warnings):

```
UWORD word2 = (UWORD) (ratio * word1);
```

Note: this will chop off the decimals, if you need proper rounding try the [`round()` function](http://www.codecogs.com/reference/computing/c/math.h/round.php), available from `math.h`. (Again, with proper casting!)